# What happens under the hood when I call a Rust dylib from native C code?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

Say, I have some dummy library written in Rust:

```
#![crate_type = "dylib"]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo() {
    println!("bork!");
}
```

And I'm using it from C native code like that:

```
void foo();
int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm particularly interested in two things:

- Does additional threads gets spawned on the Rust function call?
- How much blocking happen on such call - mutexes, locks, memory allocations on heap, anything like that.

I'm thinking of using Rust for real-time DSP applications and therefore I must be aware of any blocking operations that take place here. But I'm not enough hardcore to dig in actual C-Rust interop implementation myself..

Comment: You may be interested in [RustAudio](https://github.com/RustAudio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing special happens. Compiled Rust code that is exported with `extern C` looks just the same as any other native code.

> Does additional threads gets spawned on the Rust function call?

No threads are created, unless your code creates them.

> How much blocking happen on such call - mutexes, locks, memory allocations on heap, anything like that.

No, unless your code does such.